# "Le moindre" et "le plus petit"

Tags: usage, mathématiques, comparatifs

Pourquoi dit-on couramment (par exemple) :

> le plus petit commun multiple

et non

> [le moindre commun multiple](https://books.google.fr/books?id=JEkGDQAAQBAJ&pg=PA163&lpg=PA163&dq=le%20moindre%20commun%20multiple&source=bl&ots=puXJgloor2&sig=ACfU3U3pYTbMce7FHL_dG1GDy38jZqRcGA&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiX9vSKxdfkAhWRAWMBHS9XBSMQ6AEwIHoECAgQAQ#v=onepage&q=le%20moindre%20commun%20multiple&f=false)

?

Comment: Parce qu'il n'existe pas de *pludre commun diviseur* ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bonne question et l'exemple que tu donnes dans l'OP prouve que... cela pourrait se dire ainsi.

Restreint à l'exemple que tu cites, l'explication, pour ce qui est de l'usuel, tient à ce qu'on aborde cette notion en quasi simultanéité avec le : ***Plus Grand*** Commun Diviseur.

Que trouve-t-on spontanément en symétrique à *plus grand* ? Eh bien... *plus petit* évidemment et non *moindre*.

Ajoutons à cela le fait que *moindre* est souvent employé (sens B du TLF) pour des valeurs non quantifiables (*moindre des choses, moindre des politesses...*) et que l'on ne peut évidemment laisser cette impression de *non quantifiable* pour un PPCM.